# remove or unbind function on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a image zoom function.
I basically want to be able to click zoom on and zoom off, which will enable zoom or disable zoom function.

I have it working if I click zoom on, But I cannot work out how to remove the function.

To destroy or taking-off zooming effect from any image you can use following code apparently if that helps.

```
$("img").image_zoomer("destroy");
```

This fiddle will explain better.

https://jsfiddle.net/u5bn9dwr/3/

Thanks!

Comment: which plugin you are using?

Comment: light weight image zoomer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `unbind()` method as `$("img").unbind();` To see: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_unbind.asp